# Why do calendar events created by Siri not appear in the calendar?

Tags: macos, calendar, siri, google-calendar

I've asked Siri to add an event to my calendar. When I ask Siri "show me my calendar for Monday", the event appears:

[image: Real actual appointment]

but the event doesn't actually appear in the calendar application:

[image: No appointment]

I use my Google calendar as my default calendar, but I don't think that should make a difference. The event doesn't appear on any other device.

I have all the calendars enabled. It looks like it has added the event to the 'iCloud - Work' calendar:

[image: Calendars]

UPDATE: I received an alert reminding me of the event that morning, and since then the event appears in the calendar:

[image: Calendar entry, too late to be of any use]

Comment: Do you have that purple calendar enabled? Perhaps add a screenshot of your calendars sidebar in the Calendar app?

Comment: @grg Yeah I have all the calendars enabled. Added a screenshot.

Comment: I tried to do the exact same thing (told Siri to add an appointment to my calendar).  It worked as expected; Siri shows me the appt and on the calendar I can see it.

Comment: The calendar entry appeared in the calendar after the event. Not sure what to make of that.